# Find size of file names with space and hyphen | pass file names containing space and hyphen to "du"

Tags: shell, files, quoting, filenames, command-substitution

I have a file, which contains the name of some files. I want to find the total size of files in the list.

```
#cat filelist
/tmp-directory/connector_db_ connector_db
/tmp-directory/connector_db -connector_db
/tmp-directory/connector_db_connector_db
```

As you can see the names of the file contains space, and **more badly a hyphen (-)**. I am trying to find the total size of these files with below command.

```
#du -sch `cat filelist`
du: invalid option -- 'o'
du: invalid option -- 'n'
du: invalid option -- 'n'
du: invalid option -- 'e'
du: invalid option -- 't'
du: invalid option -- 'o'
du: invalid option -- 'r'
du: invalid option -- '_'
du: invalid maximum depth `b'
```

I tried adding " " as shown below and then tried which also failed

```
#cat filelist
"/tmp-directory/connector_db_ connector_db"
"/tmp-directory/connector_db -connector_db"
"/tmp-directory/connector_db_connector_db"

#du -sch `cat filelist`
du: invalid option -- 'o'
du: invalid option -- 'n'
.....
```

**But this works** when I use below command, directly in shell.

```
#du -sch "/tmp-directory/connector_db -connector_db"
0       /tmp-directory/connector_db -connector_db
0       total
```

So, how to handle such a situation. I have **filelist** of 3 lac files. More badly, "du -sch" is not handling the list when file list exceeds around 20000. I am splitting the list into 20000 lines with split command. **Is there any alternate method for finding the size of 3 lac files easily?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have not put quotes around command substitution, word splitting is taking place here, according to the value of `IFS` (space, tab, newline by default). You have space in filename, so e.g. `/tmp-directory/connector_db_ connector_db` is being split into two words -- `/tmp-directory/connector_db_`, `connector_db`.

You can iterate over the filenames one by one:

```
while IFS= read -r file; do du -sch -- "$file"; done <filelist
```

As your file is big, this might take some time.

Also as the files are being parsed individually, you won't have the total size shown by `du`. So you can drop `-s` and `-c`:

```
while IFS= read -r file; do du -h -- "$file"; done <filelist
```

Comment: Awsome..!
Could you please suggest a way to find the total size of the output. A typical scenario will be below.

`4.0K    /mnt/shared/5
56K     /mnt/shared/6
1.1M    /mnt/shared/7`

Comment: @midhunpmj You can get rid of `-h` and get count in bytes, and then get the sum of column 1. Something like `while ... | tee >(awk '{s+=$1} END{print s}')` The output would be in bytes, make necessary conversions.

Answer (score 1):

```
xargs -Ifile du -sch file <filelist
```

As long as no filename contains a newline, the above will call `du -sch` on each of the name in `filelist`.  `-Ifile` will cause `xargs` to replace the string `file` in the `du -sch file` command with each name read from `filelist`.

This will handle filenames with spaces and with shell globbing patterns properly (patterns will not be expanded).

Comment: Awsome..! Could you please suggest a way to find the total size of the output. A typical scenario will be below. `4.0K /mnt/shared/5 56K /mnt/shared/6 1.1M /mnt/shared/7`

Comment: @midhunpmj You can use `-k` (only) with `du` and get count in kilobytes, and then get the sum of column 1. Something like `xargs ... | awk '{ print; s += $1 } END { print s }'`. The output would be in kilobytes, make necessary conversions.